# ERROR: Function name must be a string

Tags: php, string, function

Could someone please tell me why i get this error on row 4?

```
<?
$file = ("textFile.txt");
$read = $open($file, "r");
$data = fread($read, filesize($file));
echo $data;
fclose($read);
?>
```

Comment: what error? and what is $open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$read = $open($file, "r");
```

to this:

```
$read = fopen($file, "r");
```